# Spinner in Dialog not showing items?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, spinner

I'm currently developping a small app and therefore want to add a spinner to a dialog.
I looked for several tutorials on the web on how to add items to that spinner. 
So this is what I have so far:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public void prepareNewClubSpinner(){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<String> rest = db.getRest();

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String entry : rest){
         list.add(entry);
    }

    ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinClub.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

I've checked the list with the debugger and it does contain all the entries, so the loop is filling the list correctly but the items do not show up in my spinner whatsoever.
I seem to miss something, but can't figure out what!
Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Where are you calling this  `prepareNewClubSpinner() `??

Comment: If you get your all data in `rest` arraylist then you need to pass it to the adapter of `Spinner`.

Comment: In a AsyncTask. I checked if the method is called with the debugger and some breakpoints.

Comment: Don't I do that in the ArrayAdapter Constructors last parameter?

Comment: you can do it pass it to as a last parameter.

Comment: That's what I'm doing: new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

Comment: I am telling you to do new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, rest);

Comment: So changed? Is it working now??

Comment: Oh my bad, thanks. I did what you told and it worked perfectly, however I created a new Class extending from Dialog, because the spinner was null, since it couldn't assign it. Now I outsourced the spinner to the new Dialog. I just create the Dialog in prepareNewClubSpinner and show it after creation. Now everything is working perfectly. Thanks :)